# CopyTree method in python

Tags: python, copytree

I am using the copy tree library in python (example below) however I want the script to copy the whole folder and not just the contents inside the folder. Would addition or modification would I need to rectify this issue

```
  import copy_tree from distutils.dir_util 
  copy_tree(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the folder with the same name at your destination, then use `copy_tree`?

Comment: You're input is valued however is there a way to copy the folder as a whole with the same name across?

Comment: Try [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) then.